# Expo edges and wallpaper not working after reboot

Tags: unity, compiz, desktop-background, plugins

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm using Compiz and its Wallpaper and Expo plugins.

Since yesterday, after every reboot my first wallpaper won't show anymore and the edge setting won't work, so every time I boot the pc I have to open compiz, removing and adding the setting in Expo and in Wallpaper.

I noticed similar questions up to older versions of Ubuntu but not for 14.04 and not affecting the Wallpaper plugin.

Comment: Please reference the question about older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by installing dconf:

```
`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
```

I opened dconf and at the following path:

org > compiz > profiles > plugins > core

I rearranged the plugin with 'expo' as the last one. The wallpaper wouldn't load because the 'wallpaper' plugin was loaded before the 'imgpng' one.

Hitting on "Set as default" (I use it in italian so I don't know if that's the exact translation) the problem was solved.